# Field of fractions, $F$, of $R=k[x,y]/(x^2-y^2+y^3)$ and integral closure of $R$ in $F$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, field-theory

**Question:**

Let $k$ be a field. Consider the integral domain $R=k[x,y]/(x^2-y^2+y^3)$.

(a) Show that $R$ is not a unique factorization domain.

(b) Let $F$ be the field of fractions of $R$. Find $t\in F$ such that $F=k(t)$.

(c) Determine the integral closure of $R$ in $F$.

**Answer:**

(a) I showed that in $R$, $y^2(y-1)=y^3-y^2\equiv -x^2=x(-x)$ but $y^2$ is not equivalent to one of the factors of $-x^2$ in $R$. Thus, $R$ is not an UFD.

(b),(c) However, for these parts, I have no clue. Any help/hint would be appreciated. Thanks in advance...

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2805131/11619)

Comment: I think the links collected [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3344320/11619) cover everything. To the extent that this question is a duplicate of that one. As I have earned two applicable dupehammer privileges, I won't vote right away (because my vote would be binding). Please comment.

Comment: Agreeing with Jyrki Lahtonen's duplicate suggestion: [Integral Closure of Ring $k[t,s]/(s^2 -t^2(1+t))$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3344320/integral-closure-of-ring-kt-s-s2-t21t)